# mysqldump show password in its query : php

Tags: php, mysql

im sorry stackoverflow if this is repeated

im trying to do backup thing in php it works great

```
$path_to_mysqldump = "E:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin";
$query= "$path_to_mysqldump\\mysqldump.exe -u$dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname > E:\\$backup_file ";

exec($query); 
echo $query;
```

this gives me my backup file but my password display in query ,

```
E:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot -prahul myblog > E:\myblog2013-Feb-23-13-28-40.sql
```

password - **rahul**

I want to avoid that,and im not talking about echo $query;

IM using xampp on windows

so any help much appreciated

thanks in advanced.

Comment: I hope you've already changed that password. Also, mysqldump should be ran as a user for which only admins have access to the logfiles. It's a "feature" of mysqldump. I dont know of any interactive input programs for windows though, only linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always create a new my.ini file which can be in a directory only your user can access and pass this to mysqldump.

The file will look like this:

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=root
password=rhaul
```

And you can pass this to mysqldump through the `--defaults-file` option

```
E:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe --defaults-file=C:\ProtectedDir\my.ini myblog > E:\myblog2013-Feb-23-13-28-40.sql
```